# Arduino object constructor in class sets rubbish values

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor, arduino

I am currently trying to create a class that has a member object with a non-default constructor for an Arduino project. The object is a pointer so that I can construct when `MyClass` is constructed `(MyObjClass *my_obj;)`

```
// MyObjClass:
class MyObjClass(){
    const int param;
public: 
    MyObjClass(const int param): param(param){ ... }
};

// MyClass:
class MyClass(){
     MyObjClass *my_obj;
public:
     MyClass::MyClass(const int param): my_obj(param){ ... }
};
```

It builds fine, but the value param in `my_obj` is rubbish (random value). Does it already initialize the object before the constructor call? My workaround is to use no `const` values but there must be a better way (the right way).

Comment: `MyObjClass *my_obj;` declares `my_obj` as a pointer, and you can't initialize that with `my_obj(param)`. And what are those `()` after the class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are holding pointer to `MyObjClass` and try to init him with some `int`, the 
right way will be `my_obj(new MyObjClass(param))`.

Also I would suggest to use smart pointers to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: can I use the STL for an Arduino?

Comment: @user2980891 From what I know its not supported at least not officially, here some not official stl for arduino: https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus